# How to create dataframes from chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have huge scv file(630 mln rows),and my computer can t read it in 1 dataframe(out of memory)(After it i wanna to teach model for each dataframe).I did 630 chunks, and wanna create dataframe from each chunk(It s will 630 dataframes). Cant find or undestand no one solution of this situation.Can someone support me pls. Mb i think wrong in general and someone can say smtng new opinion on this situation. Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

lol=0
def load_csv():
    path="D:\\mml\\"
    csv_path = os.path.join(path,"eartquaqe_train.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path,sep=',',chunksize=1000000)
dannie = load_csv()

for chunk in dannie:
    lol=lol+1
print(lol)

630
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) method and specify either the **chunksize** parameter or create an iterator over all you csv rows using **skiprows** like:

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'D:\...'

a = list(range(0,6300))

for line in range(0,6300-630,630):
    df = pd.read_csv(path,skiprows=a[0:line]+a[line+630:])
    print(df)
```

**OR**

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'D:\...'

df = pd.read_csv(path,chunksize=6300)
for chunk in df:
    print(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
for chunk in dannie:
    chunk.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(lol))
    lol+=1
```

[Read here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) for more info